# find all the partial limits of this sequence

Tags: calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

i need to find all the partial limits (is that the current terminology? i mean the limits of all possible subsequences for a given sequence)

> $a_n = \sqrt[n]{4^2 + 2^n}        $
>
> find all partial sums,also find $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n$ and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n$

i couldn't really find any similar questions with regards to these  types of questions,
if somone could also point me to what to google for that would be great!

Comment: check for possible typing errors cause now $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ so there's not much to check

Comment: $a_n  \to \infty$, as do all the limits you mentioned.

Comment: sorry for that, its the n'th root now

Comment: the sequence is convergent, hence it has a unique finite limit, try to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence's limit was asked just yesterday. Here's my answer (hint, in fact):

$$\sqrt[n]{2^n}\le\sqrt[n]{16+2^n}\stackrel{\text{For}\;n\ge 4}\le\sqrt[n]{2\cdot 2^n}$$

Comment: i used the squeezing theorm to prove that it converges to 2, could you also answer my other question, how do i fnd similar questions to this (with ACTUAL partial limits)

Comment: There are millions of sites in the web with limits of sequences, basic calculus, etc., besides hundreds of books. Do a search.

Comment: What about the partial limits and the lim(inf/sup) ?